# Bind CheckBoxDataGridViewColumn from Datatable

Tags: c#, data-binding, datagridview, datatable

I am trying to fill DataGridView from dataTable, in gridview i initialized a checkbox column named : IsItemEnabled ( i only changed the name and text header from designer ).

In the DataTable Initialization, i added this column ad follow :

```
        MyDataTable = new DataTable();
        DataColumn[] columns = {
                new DataColumn()
                {
                    DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String"),//or other type
                    ColumnName = "Id"      //or other column name
                },
                new DataColumn()
                {
                    DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Boolean"),//or other type
                    ColumnName = "IsItemEnabled"      //or other column name
                },

            };
```

also, i added the values to datatable as follow :

```
            foreach (var element in data)
            {
                var row = MyDataTable.NewRow();
                row["Id"] = element.Id;
                row["IsItemEnabled"] = element.IsItemEnabled;
                MyDataTable.Rows.Add(row);
            }
ItemsGV.DataSource = MyDataTable;
```

everything is ok, except the checkbox column, when the form loaded, there is two check boxes column, the first is the one i initialized from designer ( and it has a wrong data ), and the second is generated automatically, and its header is : "IsItemEnabled" ( and it has the right data ).

while debugging : datagridview has 3 column with  names : "Id, IsItemEnabled, IsItemEnabled".

there is no exception despite we have two columns with the same name "IsItemEnabled".

Thanks,

Comment: As you said you are initializing a column from designer and again adding it dynamically in code behind. So there should be two columns with same name. Do not initialized any column in designer then there should be only one column.

Comment: i didn't initialized any new column to datagriview from code ! i just initialized a datatable column with the same name of the datagridview column, i want datatable column to be filled in the datagridview one